# Multi-Platform Application Versioning

Tags: version-control, versioning

We are developing an application in which there is PHP/MySQL based administration panel, iOS App, Android App and Kiosk App. We have just released first version. Therefore every platform's v1.0 for now.

Now since more and distinct features are introducing at each platform; Ex: too few changes/features on Kiosk and too many on Mobile apps etc; we're in confusion how to keep versions of all platforms tied together to avoid confusion in next and future releases.

Has anybody run into such? How to deal with it?

Comment: Read about tags in Git and Subversion

Comment: If it's single app - you have single version at a time. **But** if it's really 4 independent app, why not use 4 independent versioning? Please elaborate. And deeper details are SCM-specific (especially if 4 apps must be deployed as bundle and compability-issues matter)